# unable to get forwarded ref out of react select reusable component

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I recently learned react and used react select to create a reusable drop down component but now I cant extract the value to pass to the back end. for example in the code below, the console log always logs we have undefined.

```js
import { forwardRef, useRef } from "react";
import ReactSelect from "react-select";

let DUMMY_DATA = [
    {"name": "DS","value": "DS"},
    {"name": "DA","value": "DA"},
    {"name": "QA","value": "QA"}
]

const Select = forwardRef((props, ref) => (

    console.log("ref is ",ref),
  <ReactSelect
      ref={ref}
      options = {props.data}
    getOptionLabel={e => (
     <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', color: '#1A202C', fontFamily:'Avenir LT Std'}}>
       <span style={{ marginLeft: 6 }}>{e.name}</span>
     </div>
   )}
      {...props}

   />

));



function DraftPage() {
    const projectInputRef = useRef();

    function submitHandler(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    const enteredProject = projectInputRef.current.value;
    const enteredData = {project: enteredProject}

    console.log("we have", projectInputRef.current.value);
    }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <h1>Project</h1>
      <Select options={DUMMY_DATA} ref={projectInputRef}/>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
export default DraftPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

With what you have - you need to reach your value using

```
console.log("we have", projectInputRef.current.state.selectValue[0]);
```

You could figure that out with `console.log("we have", projectInputRef.current);` and inspecting what you actually got and where to look for a value.

It will be better to create a state variable with `useState` and pass this value and a setter to your `<Select>` component. Which will be super-easy due to you have `{...props}` in your `ReactSelect` component.

```
const Select = (props) => {
  return (
    <ReactSelect
      options={props.data}
      getOptionLabel={(e) => (
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            color: "#1A202C",
            fontFamily: "Avenir LT Std"
          }}
        >
          <span style={{ marginLeft: 6 }}>{e.name}</span>
        </div>
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

function DraftPage() {
  const [projectSelectData, setProjectSelectData] = useState();

  function submitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("we have", projectSelectData);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <h1>Project</h1>
      <Select
        options={DUMMY_DATA}
        value={projectSelectData}
        onChange={setProjectSelectData}
      />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit relaxed-varahamihira-qkiv8l]

And please, format your code, it is very hard to read.